# jQuery ajax load binary image from webapi 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem that when i call my API to get the image, i get the image in binary. I think so...

```
ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();

byte[] resourceByteArray = (byte[])imageConverter.ConvertTo(_Obj.GetImage(), typeof(byte[]));

MemoryStream dataStream = new MemoryStream(resourceByteArray);
response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/" + parameters.ImageFormat);
```

The frontend code.

```
$("#formoid").submit(function (event) {

/* stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault();

/* get some values from elements on the page: */
var $form = $(this),
url = $form.attr('action');
/* Send the data using post */
var posting = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: posting
}).done(function (data) {
$('#output').html('<img src="data:image/PNG;base64' + data + '" />');
});
});
```

The final result is:

```
<img src="data:image/PNG;base64�PNG

���
IHDR�����@��������sRGB�������gAMA�����a���   pHYs�������o�d����IDATx^���W��}�}��s�{�s���g�t��epww��N ��I �  �@�@�]�'F���o���ݫv�������&lt;�g�k������Uk��k���P��+��eˢT�R��`��%J�p�¾��\��`pGƪ\k0\i��!%0���`�
```

Comment: Looks like an Encoding issue with the data from Ajax Response. 
Try parsing json and
Try changing it to suitable format like
Base64 etc. You can handle this from server side too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `<img src="data:image/PNG;base64'` the `base64` part is because you need to return a `Base64` string instead of array of bytes therefore you need to convert your `byte[]` to 64Base using: `Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)`

So using your code as example:

```
ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
byte[] resourceByteArray = (byte[])imageConverter.ConvertTo(_Obj.GetImage(), typeof(byte[]));
```

Your WebApi method should be returning:

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(resourceByteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much into the asp and .NET but you should probably convert your binary array in text by using [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, before putting it in response.